# What would the fastest way for microscopic humanoids to spread across the world?

Tags: technological-development, colonization, colonies, ecology, microscopic

*As part of a series of questions that I've been doing about microscopic humanoids ...*

In my world, there are a race of microscopic humanoid organisms (0.3 mm - 0.33 mm). They live in a variety of biomes, such as leaf litter, stone and on plants and trees. In terms of technological advancement, they are near the bronze age and merely need to find/discover metal. They have domesticated pseudoscorpions, aphids, spider mites and white flies. Being in number 860,000 strong, can mass produce "spider" silk, and have spears (for poking, not throwing), stone "swords". They have silk armor, chariots (sleds) pulled by pseudoscorpions and they can produce vinegar, formaldehyde, atropine and nicotine, although not in extremely great quantities. Most importantly, they can produce and conduct static electricity.

They speak one , homogeneous language , and have a system of writing and number. Their major advancements in technology and information are in Biology, Entomology, Biochemistry, Transportation, Algebra, and Geometry. Due to their worship of their two gods , a god of science and a god of discovery, their [scientific progress due to religion](http://fubini.swarthmore.edu/~ENVS2/S2008/mbonest1/religion.htm) ( ironic as that may be ) Is even farther augmented

Their current range is a 500 square foot backyard , including expeditions and colonization of the front yard

What is the fastest was that they might increase their range / spread beyond the back yard?

Comment: Dandelion or other light seed pods from plants that spread using wind would seem an obvious choice.

Comment: I'm reminded of the *Far Side* strip captioned "Be a Virus, See the World". Hitching a ride on others seems like a good idea.

Comment: I don't know if Theocles intends to write their timeline this far, but I wonder how powered flight would work at that scale. Could these people eventually make zeppelins, planes, and stuff if that nature at that size? Could they eventually manage a space program?

Comment: Also, this isn't long enough to justify writing it as an answer, they might be able to tame a small flying animal to ride around on. Maybe even the aphids. But this is likely not possible due to limitations of the minds of the insects.

Comment: @user14837 Possibly , but they might look very different from normal planes , think dandelion seeds with wings ,a little propeller , and collapsible plumage ( taken from Oldcat's idea) . About the timeline , I'm thinking of copyrighting it first before a do that , but a rough outline can be provided. Lastly , concerning the insects , something like spurs , false chemical signals , or pulling of the antenna can be used to "train" them , or they can be bred for intelligence first, then trained to follow simple instructions.

Comment: Have you addressed the fact that smaller creatures will receive less light, thus being left in the dark - and other physiological aspects? Just curious, they may be more difficult than travel lol

Answer (score 2):

Too easy.

1- Best and foremost method would be to send a few volunteers to go and live on other (larger) creatures such as normal sized bears, wolves, tigers etc. These animals travel huge distances, carrying your little dudes with them.

2- If there are *normally sized humans* in the world, taking a ride with them would be the fastest way possible.

3- Hitching rides on wasps (specially the larger ones, to not be detectable to them) would provide you with a form of uncontrollable airplane.

4- Hitch free rides on wind-dispersed seeds.

5- Drill holes in *really* strong and sturdy seeds. Persuade families to live in them. With gales and strong winds, those would be flung miles away. Being very strong, they would not break and your people inside would not get injured. Once the wind settles, your people can start populating that place.

Answer (score 1):

Flying would be an excellent choice. Hitch a ride on a larger flying insect or bird.

If water runs through their backyard, or even as periodic flood (rain, or sprinkler) events, boats would also be relatively quick.